# Extract substring from a field with single AWK in AIX

Tags: awk, grep, ksh, aix

I have a file, `file`, with content like:

```
stringa    8.0.1.2     stringx
stringb    12.01.0.0    stringx
```

I have to get a substring from field 2 (the first two values with the dot).
I am currently doing `cat file | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1"."$2}'` and am getting the expected output:

```
8.0
12.01
```

How can I do this with a single AWK?

I have tried with match(), but I am not seeing an option for a back reference.

Comment: Single AWK what? Single AWK line? Single AWK file? Single AWK expression? Single AWK regular expression? A [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```
awk '{ split($2,str,"."); print
```

Output:

```
str[1]"."str[2] }' file
8.0
12.01
```

Also, keep in mind that your `cat` is not needed. Simply give the file directly to `awk`.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), please try following command once.

```
grep -oP '^\S+\s+\K[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** I am using GNU `grep` here. Using its `-oP` options to print the matched part and enable [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) with `-P` option here. In the *main* program, matching from starting non-space characters followed by one or more spaces, then using the `\K` option to forget that match. Then matching one or more digits occurrences followed by a dot; which is further followed by digits. If a match is found then it prints the matched value.

Comment: grep -oP '^\S+\s+\K([[:digit:]]+\.){3}[[:digit:]]+' file
8.0.1.2
12.01.0.0

Comment: @vijesh, its been edited please see my latest solution once.

Comment: It prints the whole field2

Comment: @vijesh, yes please. its been edited please see my latest/updated solution once.

Comment: grep -oP '^\S+\s+\K[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+' file Works!

Answer (score 2):

I would use GNU AWK's [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function as follows. Let the *file.txt* content be

```
stringa    8.0.1.2     stringx
stringb    12.01.0.0    stringx
```

Then

```
awk '{split($2,arr,".");print arr[1]"."arr[2]}' file.txt
```

Output:

```
8.0
12.01
```

Explanation: split at `.` the second field and put elements into array `arr`.

*(Tested in [Gawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 2):

You could match *digits* . *digits* from the second column and print if there is a match:

```
awk 'match($2, /^[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+/) {
    print substr($2, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
' file
```

Output

```
8.0
12.01
```

Answer (score 2):

Also with GNU `awk` and `gensub()`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/([[:digit:]]+[.][[:digit:]]+)(.*)/,"\\1","g",$2)}' file
8.0
12.01
```

- `gensub()` provides the ability to specify components of a regexp in the replacement text using parentheses in the regexp to mark the components and then specifying `\\n` in the replacement text, where `n` is a digit from 1 to 9.

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps not use AWK at all (or any other external program, for that matter), but rely on the field-splitting capabilities of the shell and some variable expansion. For instance:

```
 # printf "%s\n%s\n" "stringa    8.0.1.2     stringx" \
                     "stringb    12.01.0.0    stringx" |\
   while read first second third junk ; do
        printf "=%s= =%s= =%s=\n" "$first" "$second" "$third"
   done
   =stringa= =8.0.1.2= =stringx=
   =stringb= =12.01.0.0= =stringx=
```

As you can see, the value is captured in the variable "$second" already and you just need to further isolate the parts you want to see—the first and second part separated by a dot. You can do that either with parameter expansion:

```
 # variable="8.0.1.2"
 # echo ${variable%.*.*}
   8.0
```

Or like this:

```
 # variable="12.01.0.0"
 # echo ${variable%${variable#*.*.}}
   12.01
```

Or you can use a further *read* statement to separate the parts and then put them back together:

```
 # variable="12.01.0.0"
 # echo ${variable} | IFS=. read parta partb junk
 # echo ${parta}.${partb}
   12.01
```

So, putting all together:

```
 # printf "%s\n%s\n" "stringa    8.0.1.2     stringx" \
                     "stringb    12.01.0.0    stringx" |\
   while read first second third junk ; do
        printf "%s\n" "$second" | IFS=. read parta partb junk
        printf "%s.%s\n" "$parta" "$partb"
   done
   8.0
   12.01
```